# Insert into select in SQL server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to convert data table to xml. It works fine. I want to store this converted xml in another table, So I tried using insert into select statement but it throws an error

> The FOR XML clause is not allowed in a INSERT statement.

My query:

```
insert into table1 (column1)
select * from table2 
for xml raw('product'),root('productDetails');
```

Comment: Please tag your RDBMS (sql server, oracle, my sql, etc).

Comment: @Veljko89: It throws error as Incorrect syntax near 'pro'

Comment: I messed it up, can't work like that, what does `select*from table2 for xml raw('product'),root('productDetails');` returns? which columns? basicly have that as inner select, and in outer select have columns you wish to insert

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Updated :
This is tougher than i thought . what we have to do is

1. Save Xml in variable
2. then save Variable data to Table.(I think this can be simplified )

Code :

```
 CREATE TABLE #MyXMLTable
 (
   xCol XML
 ) ;

DECLARE @testXML XML 

SET @testXML = (
select * from "Product"
FOR XML RAW ('Product'), ROOT ('Products'));

select @testXML ;

INSERT  INTO #MyXMLTable ( xCol )
SELECT  @testXML;

SELECT * from #MyXMLTable
```

[using-the-for-xml-clause-to-return-query-results-as-xml](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/learn-sql-server/using-the-for-xml-clause-to-return-query-results-as-xml/)

[insert-transact-sql](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/insert-transact-sql)

Comment: @Veljko89 the error is coming because the now data is XML :)